# Doubt on the definition of a regular surface - do Carmo's Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

The definition I am given is the follwing:

**Definition.** $S \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ is a regular surface if, $\forall p \in S$, $\exists V \in \mathbb{R^3}: V \cap S \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ is the codomain of a regular parametrized surface.

**My problems understanding this.** From my understanding I concluded the following:

Let $\phi (u_1,u_2) = (x(u_1,u_2),y(u_1,u_2),z(u_1,u_2))$, $\phi:U \subset \mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ be a regular parametrized surface. If $S=\phi(U)$ then S is a regular surface.

But does the definition also let me conclude something for $S$ for the cases when $S \subset \phi(U)$ and $\phi(U) \subset S$? i.e., can I conclude if $S$ is a regular surface (or not) in the cases where $S\subset \phi(U)$ and $\phi(U)\subset S$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more plain language, do Carmo's definition says $S$ is a surface if every point $p$ in $S$ has a neighborhood $V$ in space (note *subset*, not *element*) such that $V \cap S$ is the image of an immersion of a non-empty plane open set.

As you say, $\phi(U)$ is a regular surface with your notation. The uncertainty appears to result from the order that various data are given to us:

1. We start with a subset $S$ in Euclidean three-space.
2. We pick an arbitrary point $p$ of $S$, and ask if
3. There exists an open set $V \subseteq\mathbf{R}^{3}$ containing $p$ and
4. An open set $U$ in the plane and
5. An immersion (regular mapping) $\phi:U \to V \cap S$.

If *yes*, then $S$ is a *surface*.

The choices in each item depend on the choices of preceding items. In programming terms, $V$, $U$, and $\phi$ are "locally scoped variables".

Note that *by definition* we have $\phi(U) = V \cap S \subseteq S$.

By contrast, the question "[Can we conclude $S$ is a surface] when $S \subset \phi(U)$[...]?" is strange-sounding because $S$ is being chosen after $U$ and $\phi$. In the programming analogy, the question treats $U$ and $\phi$ as having meaning "outside their scope". That's not how the definition works.

In the hope this clarifies: If $U$ is a non-empty open set in the plane and if $\phi:U \to \mathbf{R}^{3}$ is an immersion, then by do Carmo's definition the image $S = \phi(U)$ is a surface. In fact, if $V$ is an open set containing $\phi(U)$, then our mapping $\phi:U \to \phi(U)$ satisfies the definition, and therefore demonstrates $S$ is a surface.

(Technical caution: Many authors assume more in the definition of a regular surface, namely that in points 4. and 5., $\phi$ is *proper*, i.e., preimages of compact sets are compact, so the inverse mapping $\phi^{-1}:\phi(U) \to U$ is continuous.)

Comment: Really good explanation! I am left with one further doubt, which is the following: I am facing an exercise (I don't know if it's from do Carmo) that gives me a parametrization $\phi: U \subset \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ such that $\phi(u_1,u_2) = (u_1,\frac{\sin(u_2)}{u1},\frac{\cos(u_2)}{u_1})$, where $U = \mathbb{R^+} \times (0,2\pi)$. I am now asked to show that the codomain (i.e. $\phi(U)$ is contained in $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: x^2(y^2+z^2)=1\}$. I do this by simply substituing and veryfying that $\phi$ satisfies the conditon. Is $S$ regular surface?

Comment: I just noticed  that for $u_2 = 0 \vee u_2 = 2\pi$, we have points in the surface $S$ but not parametrized by $\phi(u_1,u_2)$ which means that I can't conclude that $S$ is a regular surface right away. Altought, if I find other(s) regular parametrized surfaces (i.e., parametrizations) that cover those kind of points, would I be able to say that $S$ is, indeed, a regular surface (since I have found one or more parametrizations that cover the whole surface)?

Comment: The set $S$ does contain $\phi(U)$, which would be shown just as you say. As for whether $S$ is a surface, do you have a good visual image? Re: the second comment, $\phi$ does not parametrize all of $S$, but as you say, choosing a suitable angle range "covers" the points $u_{2} = 0$ missed by $\phi$. (IIRC, note that $\phi$ does not quite parametrize _half_ of $S$.)

Comment: I believe I can prove (quite easily) that $S$ is a regular surface using one of do Carmo's propositons (the one that uses $f$ a differentiable function such that $a$ is a regular value of $f$ implies that $f^{-1}(a)$ being a regular surface). I was just wondering if I could prove it by definition aswell. I understand that $\phi$ doesn't parametrize "half" of $S$ since $u_1 \in \mathbb{R^+}$. Altought, let's imagine that $u_1 \in \mathbb{R\{0\}$$. Would this be a an alternative such that $\phi(U)=S$ and so, implying that $S$ is a regular surface? Thanks for your help!

Comment: _Yes_ to both points. :)